# How to get information when some one change the value in edittext in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-edittext, edit

As I have the next button and webview which is attached with the webview. And My website refreshes with the value upgradation, But when someone types the value in the text field app web view doesn't reload. So please help me to reload my webview when the value is changed or typed new value thank you.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class phy_btn extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView justme;
    EditText data;
    Button btn, next;
    String half;
    String i, nuller;
    public static String Extra_name = "1";
    WebView webView;
    NetworkChangeListener networkChangeListener = new NetworkChangeListener();

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(networkChangeListener, filter);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_btn);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.toolbar_title);
//        justme = findViewById(R.id.nit);
        query quu = new query(this);
        data = findViewById(R.id.enter);
        btn=findViewById(R.id.previous);
        next= findViewById(R.id.next);
        i = "1";
        webView =findViewById(R.id.web);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Practical");
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Physical Botany");
    enter code here

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quu.linkker( new query.VolleyCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void linkker(String date, String numer, String answer1, String imag1) {
                        i = data.getText().toString();
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(i);
                        value++;
                        String nepali = Integer.toString(value);
                        half = date.split(".app/")[0];
                        String killer = half+".app/btnphy/"+nepali+".html";
                        data.setText(nepali);
                        webView.loadUrl(killer);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                quu.linkker( new query.VolleyCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void linkker(String date, String numer, String answer1, String imag1) {
                        i = data.getText().toString();
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(i);
                        value--;
                        String nepali = Integer.toString(value);
                        half = date.split(".app/")[0];
                        String killer = half+".app/btnphy/"+nepali+".html";
                        data.setText(nepali);
                        webView.loadUrl(killer);
                        if (i != "1") {
                            webView.loadUrl(killer);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        quu.linkker( new query.VolleyCallback(){


            @Override
            public void linkker(String date, String numer, String answer1, String imag1) {



                half = date.split(".app/")[0];
                String killer = half+".app/btnphy/"+i+".html";
//                justme.setText(killer);
                if (i != "1") {
                    webView.loadUrl(killer);
                }
                webView.loadUrl(killer);
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Comment: Your EditText data has an addOnTextChangedListener method that accepts a TextWatcher object. So you can create a class that extends TextWatcher and override its onTextChanged method, or Java will also allow you to do that inline by using '''new TextWatcher(){}''' and the IDE should start hinting for what overrides are admissible/required.

Comment: Sorry can you please refer me location of Code as, I tried to implement, I am unable to implement it.